# Por que as arrays, dentro de um objeto, são undefined na requisição da api usando axios?

Tags: javascript, react, axios

Eu criei uma api que envia essa informação:

```
{ 
  title: 'algum título', 
  content: ['vários parágrafos']
}
```

O método que recebe os dados é o seguinte:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000");
    let api = response.data;

    this.setState({ data: api });
  }
```

Tanto o título quanto o conteúdo são recebidos corretamente, eu consigo visualizar os dados fazendo um log, porém, o tipo da variável é incorreto.

```
console.log(typeof api.title) // string
console.log(typeof api.content) // undefined
```

Para resolver o caso, utilizo os colchetes. Só assim consigo usar o map.

```
<div>
  <h1> {this.state.data.title} </h1>
  {[this.state.data.content].map(elem => <p> {elem} <br/ > </p>) }
</div>
```

A questão não é que não consigo resolver o problema, mas eu gostaria de compreende-lo. Entender o motivo pelo qual isso acontece.

Comment: De um console.log this.state.data e cole na pergunta

Comment: Tem certeza que a API está retornando o esperado? Cuidado com erros de ortografia também, por exemplo, retornar "cotent" em vez de "content". Você pode verificar iss na aba "network" do Dev Tools

Comment: isso não pode ser causado por como a informação sai da API? ela deveria sair como Array mas está saindo com a informação porém sem Type Definido, sua API é do tipo que exige type de variáveis?

Comment: Isso não faz sentido. O `console.log(typeof api.content)` está sendo executado antes ou depois de `this.setState({ data: api })`?

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, o que ocorreu foi um erro na passagem dos dados para o state do react:

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: '' };
  }
```

O fato do objeto data ser instanciado como uma string fez com que os dados fossem interpretados de forma errada. Eu não entendo o motivo, sinceramente, mas consigo imaginar que talvez seja algo relacionado a tipagem dinâmica. A solução foi bem simples:

```
this.state = { data: [] }; // troquei '' para []
```